# how can i get only date from "2017-11-13T00:00:00" in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I get only date from "2017-11-13T00:00:00" using angularjs. 
I have tried using below method.

```
&scope.date = "2017-11-13T00:00:00";
var dateParts = $filter('date')(new Date(&scope.date), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

But it's not working for me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

$scope.format = "M-d-yyyy";

$scope.date = dateFilter(new Date("2017-11-13T00:00:00"), format)

source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I tried  $scope.dateout = "2017-11-13T00:00:00";                   

                    $scope.format = "M-d-yyyy";

                    $scope.dateParts = dateFilter(new Date($scope.dateout), $scope.format);   still im not getting it..

Comment: inject dateFilter in your controller, i tested your code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a typo `&scope` -> `$scope` and it should solve your problem.

Tried the below code in local and was able to see "2017-11-13" in the console.

```
$scope.myDate = '2017-11-13T00:00:00';
```

`console.log($filter('date')(new Date($scope.myDate),'yyyy-MM-dd'))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using $scope. but its not working.